# Android: When to bind controls to database

Tags: android, sqlite, binding, android-activity, textview

When is the best time during an activity to bind my controls (such as textview) to values in my SQLite database?  I thought I remember reading that you should do this in onStart() but most of the examples I have seen set the values in onCreate().

Here is an example of the code:

```
//I think this always goes in onCreate
MyDb db = new MyDB();
db.open();
Textview tvTextView;
tvTextView = findViewById(R.id.tv1);

//I'm not sure whether to put this in onCreate(), onStart(), or onResume()
tvTextView.setText(db.getMyText());
```

Normally MyDb and TextView would be variables for the whole class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using laoders in the fragment support library.  This example shows how to use loaders (using the ones in the HC API) to load a cursor from the contacts DB and update a list adapter when you get the first result and as it updates:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentListCursorLoader.html

Using this to fill in your own data is basically the same, but instead of setting it in an adapter when you get the cursor back you can just pull the data you want out and set it in your fields.

Article on how to get the support library version of these:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html

I strongly recommend this as the preferred, modern way to load data from cursors and other sources.  It takes care of a lot of things for you to make sure you are doing things the best way: it does the query asynchronously so your UI doesn't block waiting for it, it monitors the data for changes and gives you a clean way to update from a new cursor when there is a change, it takes care of integrating with the activity lifecycle, it propagates previous data across activity instances when an activity is destroyed and new instance created due to a config change, etc.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer.  It might be a bit of an overkill for my situation though.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the behavior you desire. If you only want the text to be set a single time, `onCreate()` will suffice. If you want the text to be updated each time your activity is brought back to the foreground you can use `onStart()`, `onRestart()` or even `onResume()`. Obviously if you want the text to be updated even more often (e.g. every time the database changes) you'll need to do something more elaborate.